# Import model methods in other model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework for API where I need to use methods from one model into another. But, this results in

> ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to circular import)

My models samples are as follows:

**Model A**

```
from ..B.models import B
Class A:
    @classmethod
    def foo():
        b = B()
        b.bar()
```

**Model B**

```
from ..A.models import A
Class B:
    @classmethod
    def bar():
        a = A()
        a.foo()
```

I understand the error is being caused to due to *ciruclar import*.
Is there any way to import methods in each other's model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `get_model` function which is designed for lazy model imports.

```
from django.apps import apps
YourModel = apps.get_model('your_app_name', 'YourModel')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_model` and import the other model when the function is called:

```
from django.apps import apps

Class B:
    @classmethod
    def bar():
        A = apps.get_model('app_name', 'A')
        a = A()
        a.foo()
```

It's possible to do it the other way around also.